PgBackRest Unnecessary Data Size
I am taking backups of my PostgreSQL database with PgBackrest, performing a full backup once a week and incremental backups for five days.
I store the backups on a separate backup server, apart from my production server. However, my backup files are taking up more than twice the space of my production database.
Production database disk information:

Backup disk information:

Backup archive and backup folder size information:

Prod Server bcbackrest config information;
[global]
log-level-file=info
repo1-host=(backup_server_hostname)

archive-async          = y
process-max            = 2
spool-path             = /var/spool/pgbackrest

[global:archive-get]
process-max=8

[global:archive-push]
process-max=8

[my_stanza]
pg1-path=/cluster_path
pg1-port=cluster_port

Backup Server bcbackrest config information;
[global]
repo1-path=/backup_path
repo1-retention-full=1
process-max=8
start-fast=y
log-level-console=info
log-level-file=info


[my_stanza]
pg1-host=(prod_server_hostname)
pg1-path=/cluster_path
pg1-port=cluster_port

The size of the "Archive" file on my backup server is very large. Besides that, my "Backup" file seems to be larger than necessary. What should I do?
Thanks.
pgbackrest info;
db (current)
        wal archive min/max (13): 000000010000018700000057/0000000100000222000000C0

        full backup: 20240512-090003F
            timestamp start/stop: 2024-05-12 09:00:03+03 / 2024-05-12 10:13:21+03
            wal start/stop: 000000010000018700000057 / 000000010000018700000057
            database size: 586.8GB, database backup size: 586.8GB
            repo1: backup set size: 560.8GB, backup size: 560.8GB

        incr backup: 20240512-090003F_20240513-000005I
            timestamp start/stop: 2024-05-13 00:00:05+03 / 2024-05-13 00:14:44+03
            wal start/stop: 000000010000018B000000AC / 000000010000018B000000AC
            database size: 595.5GB, database backup size: 98GB
            repo1: backup set size: 569GB, backup size: 91.6GB
            backup reference list: 20240512-090003F

        incr backup: 20240512-090003F_20240514-000005I
            timestamp start/stop: 2024-05-14 00:00:05+03 / 2024-05-14 00:26:27+03
            wal start/stop: 00000001000001AE0000008E / 00000001000001AE00000096
            database size: 652.3GB, database backup size: 191GB
            repo1: backup set size: 623GB, backup size: 181GB
            backup reference list: 20240512-090003F, 20240512-090003F_20240513-000005I

        incr backup: 20240512-090003F_20240515-000006I
            timestamp start/stop: 2024-05-15 00:00:06+03 / 2024-05-15 00:29:44+03
            wal start/stop: 00000001000001CD000000E5 / 00000001000001CE0000001D
            database size: 704GB, database backup size: 200.2GB
            repo1: backup set size: 673.2GB, backup size: 189.3GB
            backup reference list: 20240512-090003F, 20240512-090003F_20240513-000005I, 20240512-090003F_20240514-000005I

        incr backup: 20240512-090003F_20240516-000005I
            timestamp start/stop: 2024-05-16 00:00:05+03 / 2024-05-16 00:44:23+03
            wal start/stop: 00000001000001F800000051 / 00000001000001F80000006E
            database size: 773GB, database backup size: 292.8GB
            repo1: backup set size: 738.2GB, backup size: 277.5GB
            backup reference list: 20240512-090003F, 20240512-090003F_20240513-000005I, 20240512-090003F_20240514-000005I, 20240512-090003F_20240515-000006I

        incr backup: 20240512-090003F_20240517-000003I
            timestamp start/stop: 2024-05-17 00:00:03+03 / 2024-05-17 00:33:44+03
            wal start/stop: 000000010000020A00000008 / 000000010000020A000000A7
            database size: 794.7GB, database backup size: 226.9GB
            repo1: backup set size: 759.0GB, backup size: 213.3GB
            backup reference list: 20240512-090003F, 20240512-090003F_20240513-000005I, 20240512-090003F_20240514-000005I, 20240512-090003F_20240515-000006I, 20240512-090003F_20240516-000005I


Collect a "pgbackrest info" to check what you really have one your backup repository.

@AdelinoSilva I added the pgbacrest info repository to the question. Could you please check? Thanks.

As you can see the full backup and the five incremental backup are using 1511GB.
repo1: backup set size: 560.8GB, backup size: 560.8GB
repo1: backup set size: 569GB, backup size: 91.6GB
repo1: backup set size: 623GB, backup size: 181GB
repo1: backup set size: 673.2GB, backup size: 189.3GB
repo1: backup set size: 738.2GB, backup size: 277.5GB
repo1: backup set size: 759.0GB, backup size: 213.3GB

The wal files archived are from 000000010000018700000057 to 0000000100000222000000C0.
As the full backup is referencing the wal 000000010000018700000057 file when the full backup as done and is the oldest archive.
I don't see any issue here, the backup repo size is due system dynamic activity, the data changes between incremental backup caused by the applications workload.

So why do my backups take up so much space? Incr backups are not the right strategy in this case? How can I find a solution to the size problem? Should I do this by changing the wal management in my postgresql database or should I change my backup strategy?
I also found this about wal archiving;
link
If I enter the value of the repo1-retention-archive-type parameter as incr, I feel like there will be an improvement in size, but I am afraid of having problems with data integrity.
